# How is field length defined in Solr/Lucene?

Tags: solr, lucene

As I understand it, a field length of a given document is the number of terms indexed in the field of the given document. However, it seems that the field length is never an integer. For instance, I've seen a document with two terms in its content field, but the content field length as calculated by Solr is actually 2.56, not 2 as I've expected. How is a field length really being calculated in Solr/Lucene?

I'm referring to the field length as it is used when calculating the score according to the BM25 similarity function, but I think that field lengths are being calculated for other ranking schemes.

Answer (score 0):

As i see in the code for BM25Similarity:

```
  public final long computeNorm(FieldInvertState state) {
    final int numTerms = discountOverlaps ? state.getLength() - state.getNumOverlap() : state.getLength();
    return encodeNormValue(state.getBoost(), numTerms);
  }
```

where state#getLength() is:

```
  /**
   * Get total number of terms in this field.
   * @return the length
   */
  public int getLength() {
    return length;
  }
```

Actually, it's an integer. Could you please tell, where do you see non integer values? SolrAdmin UI? where?

Now, as you posted the output, I found the place where it comes from:
[source](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/25295707/)

Take a look at this:

```
private Explanation explainTFNorm(int doc, Explanation freq, BM25Stats stats, NumericDocValues norms) {
    List<Explanation> subs = new ArrayList<>();
    subs.add(freq);
    subs.add(Explanation.match(k1, "parameter k1"));
    if (norms == null) {
      subs.add(Explanation.match(0, "parameter b (norms omitted for field)"));
      return Explanation.match(
          (freq.getValue() * (k1 + 1)) / (freq.getValue() + k1),
          "tfNorm, computed from:", subs);
    } else {
      float doclen = decodeNormValue((byte)norms.get(doc));
      subs.add(Explanation.match(b, "parameter b"));
      subs.add(Explanation.match(stats.avgdl, "avgFieldLength"));
      subs.add(Explanation.match(doclen, "fieldLength"));
      return Explanation.match(
          (freq.getValue() * (k1 + 1)) / (freq.getValue() + k1 * (1 - b + b * doclen/stats.avgdl)),
          "tfNorm, computed from:", subs);
    }
  }
```

So, by the field length they output: `float doclen = decodeNormValue((byte)norms.get(doc));`

```
 /** The default implementation returns <code>1 / f<sup>2</sup></code>
   * where <code>f</code> is {@link SmallFloat#byte315ToFloat(byte)}. */
  protected float decodeNormValue(byte b) {
    return NORM_TABLE[b & 0xFF];
  }

/** Cache of decoded bytes. */
  private static final float[] NORM_TABLE = new float[256];

  static {
    for (int i = 1; i < 256; i++) {
      float f = SmallFloat.byte315ToFloat((byte)i);
      NORM_TABLE[i] = 1.0f / (f*f);
    }
    NORM_TABLE[0] = 1.0f / NORM_TABLE[255]; // otherwise inf
  }
```

In fact, looking at the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25) this docLen should be

> a |D| is the length of the document D in words

Comment: I see the non integer value with explain: 2.56 = fieldLength

Comment: @mossaab Can you please add the full output of explain to your question? Because usually it contains fieldNorm or fieldWeigth and not a fieldLength.

Comment: 23.637165 = sum of:
  10.065297 = weight(title:googl in 401658357) [BM25Similarity], result of:
    10.065297 = score(doc=401658357,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0
), product of:
      7.3866553 = idf(docFreq=414179, docCount=668609139)
      1.3626325 = tfNorm, computed from:
        1.0 = termFreq=1.0
        1.2 = parameter k1
        0.75 = parameter b
        7.3254013 = avgFieldLength
        2.56 = fieldLength
  13.571868 = weight(title:hangout in 401658357) [BM25Similarity], result of:
    13.571868 = score(doc=401658357,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0
), product of:
[TRUNCATED]

Comment: @mossaab I updated my answer, it doesn't clearly answers your question but it least it points to the places in the code. Not much of a javadoc there though..

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating the previous answer "fieldLength" is calculated via complicated mathematical normalization (encoding/decoding) equation (**basically compressing 32 bit integers to 8 bits** to save disk space while storing the data) in class SmallFloat.java.

This is description of decodeNormValue() function which calculates the fieldLength in BM25:

> Default scoring implementation which {@link encodeNormValue(float) 
>   encodes} norm values as a single byte before being stored. At search
>   time,  the norm byte value is read from the index  {@link
>   org.apache.lucene.store.Directory directory} and  {@link
>   decodeNormValue(long) decoded} back to a float *norm* value. 
>   This encoding/decoding, while reducing index size, comes with the
>   price of  precision loss - it is not guaranteed that
>   *decode(encode(x)) = x*. For  instance, *decode(encode(0.89)) =
>   0.875*

Hope this helps.